# IE8 Sticky Footer Problems

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, footer, sticky-footer

If you view [this](http://www.ewsprojects.com/~lyons) in Firefox, you'll see that the bottom footer stays right with the window as you resize, move, etc. It also starts right at the bottom without a scrollbar. However, in IE8 I can't get it to sit at the bottom at the beginning OR move with the window, and probably a number of other issues. I got the code from [this site](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/), and it says it's IE compatible, so I must be doing something wrong. I had to alter the code a bit to fit my situation, but here's the IE specific css:

```
* {
margin: 0;
}

#container{
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -30px;
}

#footer, .push{
height: 30px;
width: 100%;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #565656, #303030);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#565656), to(#303030));
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#565656', endColorstr='#303030');
text-align:center;
font-family: loginfont;
font-size:13px;
color: #fff;
padding-top:5px;
clear: both;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what's going wrong? I'm absolutely clueless at this point. I hate IE...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but it can be the `padding-top:5px;` which is causing the problem. Try changing the `margin: 0 auto -30px;` to `margin: 0 auto -35px;` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your `#container` add `<div class="push"></div>` and add `position:relative;` to `#container` as negative margin will not work on static positioned elements.